# Automatically Convert Old Excel Files Upon Download

Tags: excel, google-chrome, browser, excel-2010, excel-2007

I download a lot of excel files for my job. But the "dashboard" we use outputs everything in older file formats (97-03) than my current version of Excel uses (2013). As a result, I have to "Enable Editing" and "Convert" every time I download a file. This wouldn't be a problem, but can be troublesome when I download larger datasets. I was wondering if there was a way for the file to be converted at the browser level, upon download. This way, when I open it in excel, it is already converted.

Comment: In Excel try **Options>Trust Center>Trust Center Settings>File Block Settings**. Here you can set which file types you want to open without being in Protected View.

Comment: Thanks, that helped! Do you know if there is any way to automatically get out of compatibility mode and convert the file from open?